# include header files in C

Tags: c, header

I am a newbie to C and C++ language, I have a question about header files in C:

**a.h**

```
#define HELLO (1)
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} hello;
```

**b.h**

```
#include "a.h"
#define NUMBER (3)
```

**main.c**

```
#include "b.h"
```

in `main.c`, does `struct` and `macro` defined in `a.h` can be used in `main.c`?

Comment: Yes, of course - you could have just tried this yourself, no ?

Comment: yes, I can, but I need to have some communication with others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use both Struct and MACROS in the main.c

You need to be aware of the C Compilation Process, Before main.c is being compiled or linked, there is the pre-processor step:

**Preprocessor**:

- The input to this phase is the .c File and .h Files
- The preprocess process the preprocessor keywords like #define, #ifdef, #include, etc. and generate a new .pre file or .i file after the text replacement process.
- The output of this phase is a C Code without any preprocessor keyword.

[image]

So the main.c will actually look like this:

```
#define HELLO (1)
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} hello;
#define NUMBER (3)
```

And then replace all macros, here you don't use HELLO or NUMBER, so the pure c main file will be:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used. That is the sole purpose of `#include`ing of header files.

For more information, you can see the preprocessed version of code. Use

```
gcc -E <filename.c>  //main.c, in this case
```

There you can see the presence of the `struct` and MACROS definde in the included header files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `#include` directives themselves appearing in included files have their normal effect, up to an implementation-defined limit on the number of levels of inclusion.  The "normal effect" is equivalent to textual interpolation -- that is, there is no separate scoping for the contents of included files -- so any declaration appearing in any directly or indirectly included file is visible to all code following the point of inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, #include statements can chain multiple files together. #include literally copies and pastes the contents of one file into another, so you can think of it as a one-after-another effect.